# Continued Fraction, Closest Neighbours

Tags: algorithms, continued-fractions

For setting the proper divisor/multiplier registers in a phase locked loop, I use a continued fraction expansion, which I stop if either the numerator or denominator of the fraction becomes larger than 4095. This really works well.
My question is: Does any algorithm/strategy exist, that gives me the next lower and/or higher value?

Example: with registers of size 32, to approximate pi, I find 22/7 = 3.1429.
The next lower would be 25/8 = 3.1250
The next higher would be 19/6 = 3.1667
I currently solve this by an exhaustive search, the following is equivalent matlab/octave code. The actual c-code implementation is more efficient, but this is just a short way to express the principle.

```
lo = unique((1:31)./floor((1:31)/pi));
hi = unique((1:31)./ceil((1:31)/pi));
rats(lo(2))
rats(hi(end-1))
```

So to repeat my question in a slightly other way: How to avoid the exhaustive search to find these values?

Typically what I see is that for values up to 4096, is that the closest values are
I multiply the best value up to 4096. Eg for pi ~ 22/7 = 4092/1302
Then the answers seems to be in a lot of cases

```
lo = round(pi*(1302+1))/(1302+1)
hi = round(pi*(1302-1))/(1302-1)
```

But is this not always the case.

Edit: The original message used unique(sort(...)). Since unique already sorts this was redundant.

Comment: Could you explain the rules for "next higher" and "next lower"? Continued fractions will always give the best rational approximation, what are you after instead? Using 4096 as your cutoff means they will be very precise approximations - its quite a large number to see in a continued fraction.

Comment: For my application, I need to adjust the frequency of the synthesizer in very small steps. I need to track an input frequency of several GHz. The loop time constant is several minutes. If I see my loop is lagging, I want to change the ratio of my phase locked loop to the next highest/lowest frequency. Over a matter of days the loop should track within 10^-9 on average. The brute force way can achieve this, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Can't see why you need a sort. Lets say you are approximating 3.14 using a/b where a and b are less than 32.

Comment: Can't see why you need a sort. If you are looking for a/b where a and b are less than 32, then if a/b = 3.14 you can calculate the value of a from b, which is a =[3.14 * b] if you want a smaller frequency and  [3.14 * b] + 1 if you want a larger frequency, where the square brackets mean the floor function. So you can also work out the error as you calculate the approximation and keep track of the smallest error. This simply involves stepping through 32 possible values, which is an improvement over sorting 32 values.

Comment: My problem is not just 32, but 4096. I needed the sort, since the function was not monotonic. The unique also sorts, so this is double. The c-implementation actually iterates and finds the minimum. As said the code just showed the principle. I cannot quite follow what you do with the floor(3.14 * b) + 1. Could you please give a more elaborate example where given the ratio 123/456 you find 1083/4015, which is the closest neighbour?

Comment: OK Peter, I now get hat you are trying to way with your answer. I was thinking too difficult. Actually, this was also my very naive first try. But this is nowhere near the closest neighbours. As said I already have a solution that works (brute force), but in general for these kind of questions some clever mathematician has already found some ingenious way to solve it. Just making sure I am not overlooking the obvious.

Comment: Use the stern-brocot tree !

Comment: Thank you Xoff. This is what I meant with the ingenious way. Just did a quick implementation and this finds the right answer very efficiently. At first glance it looks like a log(N) instead of N complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Stern Brocot Tree.

for any fraction $\frac{p}{q}$, compute the two (lower and higher) closest ancestors 
$\frac{p_l}{q_l}$ and $\frac{p_h}{q_h}$.

The next lower will be $$\frac{kp+p_l}{kq+q_l} $$ with the largest $k$ (could be $0$) such that numerator and denominator are in the right bound (lower than 4096). The same for the next higher. So $k=\min((4096-p_l)/p,(4096-q_l)/q)$

If your implementation is correct, computing the closest ancestors takes as long as finding the Bezout coefficient of $p$ and $q$.

---

Complete example : $\frac{17}{7}$

To find the closest lower ancestor, find the Bezout coefficients using the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

You'll find that $$17\times 5-7\times 12=1$$

Hence $\frac{12}{5}$ is the closest lower ancestor and $\frac{17-12}{7-5}=\frac{5}{2}$ is the closest upper ancestor.

Now $k=\min((4096-12)/17,(4096-5)/7)=240$.

Hence $\frac{240\times17+12}{240\times 7+5}=\frac{4092}{1685}$ is the lower closest.

Comment: In my implementation initially I start at the top of the tree, remember where I go left/right, till I find my fraction p/q, then either continue branching or traverse back and then for ph/qh take the route towards the location on the right, stopping as the number get higher than 4095. In your answer you state "The next lower will be ..." then qive an equation and telling that k could be zero. Using k = 0 this gives as a value for the next lower pl/ql. This was the definition of the next lower. I am sorry, I only have an engineering background, I am not a mathematician.

Comment: @user3310744 Perhaps I misunderstood you, but I thought that the next lower of $\frac{p}{q}$ could have a larger denominator than  $q$, that's why I added the formula with $k$. If not, then $k=0$, but if yes, you should stick to the formula with the given $k$. For example $\frac{2}{3}$ has the closest lower ancestor $\frac{1}{2}$. So $k=(4096-2)/3=1364$ and $\frac{1364\times2+1}{1364\times 3+2}=\frac{2729}{4094}$ is the closest lower fraction of $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: OK, I get it and can reproduce it. I mistook pl/ql and ph/qh as being the next lower/higher value. But these where the closest ANCESTORs. Thanks.

Comment: @user3310744 I added an example to better explain how to do it with the optimal method.

Comment: I really love it when everything falls into place. I started reading about the Stern-Brocot tree where it was presented just as fractions. Now I find that if I use the description based on 2x2 matrices, I can easily obtain the matrix for the current 'position' in the tree using the continued fraction that I already performed. This 2x2 matrix also supplies me both ancestors. Then by using Xoff's method I quickly generate its neighbours. From the implementation side it is nice for the microcontroller that everything can be performed using integer logic, no floating point needed.